# pypokereval library configure script fails with "No python development environments found"

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, configure, automake

I'm trying to compile the pypoker-eval-138.0  library for python2.7 (default on mint linux):

- [source tarball dir](http://download.gna.org/pokersource/sources/)
- [GNA pokersource site](http://gna.org/projects/pokersource/)

So when running the configure script via `./configure`, I get errors regarding the python interpreter version:

```
    ...snip...
checking for a Python interpreter with version =2.3... done
checking for a Python interpreter with version =2.4... done
checking for a Python interpreter with version =2.5... done
checking for a Python interpreter with version =2.6... done
configure: error: No python development environments found
```

Versions of python I have installed:

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python (/usr/bin/python -> python2.7)
/usr/bin/python2-dbg-config
/usr/bin/python2               /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python2.7             /usr/bin/python3.3
/usr/bin/python2.7-config      /usr/bin/python3.3m
/usr/bin/python2.7-dbg         /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2.7-dbg-config  /usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2-config        /usr/bin/python-dbg
/usr/bin/python2-dbg           /usr/bin/python-dbg-config
```

I have also tried `./configure PYTHON="/usr/bin/python2.7"` and similar but run into variants on the above issue:

```
 ...snip..
 checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
 checking whether /usr/bin/python2.7 version =2.3... configure: error: too old
```

In an effort to resolve this issue, I have spent a significant amount of time trying to change the aclocal/autoconf setup, but am not very familiar with what should be done. I have the following .m4 files that I have tried editing to varying degrees of failure:

```
 ls ./aclocal.m4 ./config/*
 ./aclocal.m4           ./config/install-sh      ./config/ltsugar.m4
 ./config/ccpython.m4   ./config/libtool.m4      ./config/ltversion.m4
 ./config/config.guess  ./config/ltmain.sh       ./config/missing
 ./config/config.sub    ./config/lt~obsolete.m4  ./config/py-compile
 ./config/depcomp       ./config/ltoptions.m4    ./config/python.m4
```

For example, `./config/ccpython.m4`:

```
 ...snip..
 AC_DEFUN([ALL_CC_PYTHON],
 [ 
 m4_define([_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST], [python2.6 python2.5 python2.4 python2.3])
 PYTHONS=''
 found_one=''
 _ONE_CC_PYTHON([=2.3], [2_3])
 if test -f "$PYTHON" ; then found_one=$PYTHON ; PYTHONS="$PYTHON $PYTHONS" ; fi
 unset PYTHON
 ...snip..
```

My question is, specifically: how do I compile a python module for 2.7 that has a configure script that only supports up to 2.6? Do I have to regenerate the configure script, or can I just pass some flag or variable to the configure script to force build for 2.7?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, that was a challenge (what could one do for reputation? :).

The hint was in Changelog

```
    * config/python.m4 (AM_PATH_PYTHON): Added python2.6 support.

    * config/ccpython.m4 (ALL_CC_PYTHON): Added python2.6 support.
```

So it should only take these files to fix to support new python version. I just replaced python 2.5 with python 2.7, reconfigured with `autoreconf` and it worked. See the complete patch below.

To make it work, make sure you have these packages installed:

```
$ apt-get install python-dev autoconf pkg-config
```

Apply the patch below and run

```
$ autoreconf
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Here is the patch (well, I had to change Makefile.am as well):

```
diff --git a/Makefile.am b/Makefile.am
index c16df82..7d66971 100644
--- a/Makefile.am
+++ b/Makefile.am
@@ -40,12 +40,12 @@ _pokereval_2_6_la_LIBADD = ${PYTHON2_6_LIBS} ${POKER_EVAL_LIBS}
 _pokereval_2_6_la_CFLAGS = ${PYTHON2_6_CFLAGS} ${POKER_EVAL_CFLAGS} -DPYTHON_VERSION=\"2_6\" -D'VERSION_NAME(w)=w\#\#2_
 endif

-if PYTHON_2_5
-py2_5exec_LTLIBRARIES = _pokereval_2_5.la
-_pokereval_2_5_la_SOURCES = pypokereval.c
-_pokereval_2_5_la_LDFLAGS = -module -no-undefined -version-info 1:0:0
-_pokereval_2_5_la_LIBADD = ${PYTHON2_5_LIBS} ${POKER_EVAL_LIBS}
-_pokereval_2_5_la_CFLAGS = ${PYTHON2_5_CFLAGS} ${POKER_EVAL_CFLAGS} -DPYTHON_VERSION=\"2_5\" -D'VERSION_NAME(w)=w\#\#2_
+if PYTHON_2_7
+py2_7exec_LTLIBRARIES = _pokereval_2_7.la
+_pokereval_2_7_la_SOURCES = pypokereval.c
+_pokereval_2_7_la_LDFLAGS = -module -no-undefined -version-info 1:0:0
+_pokereval_2_7_la_LIBADD = ${PYTHON2_7_LIBS} ${POKER_EVAL_LIBS}
+_pokereval_2_7_la_CFLAGS = ${PYTHON2_7_CFLAGS} ${POKER_EVAL_CFLAGS} -DPYTHON_VERSION=\"2_7\" -D'VERSION_NAME(w)=w\#\#2_
 endif

 if PYTHON_2_4
diff --git a/config/ccpython.m4 b/config/ccpython.m4
index c94cbb6..46de0db 100644
--- a/config/ccpython.m4
+++ b/config/ccpython.m4
@@ -110,7 +110,7 @@ AM_CONDITIONAL([PYTHON_]$2, [test "$have_python" != "no"])

 AC_DEFUN([ALL_CC_PYTHON],
 [ 
-m4_define([_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST], [python2.6 python2.5 python2.4 python2.3])
+m4_define([_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST], [python2.6 python2.7 python2.4 python2.3])
 PYTHONS=''
 found_one=''
 _ONE_CC_PYTHON([=2.3], [2_3])
@@ -119,7 +119,7 @@ unset PYTHON
 _ONE_CC_PYTHON([=2.4], [2_4])
 if test -f "$PYTHON" ; then found_one=$PYTHON ; PYTHONS="$PYTHON $PYTHONS" ; fi
 unset PYTHON
-_ONE_CC_PYTHON([=2.5], [2_5])
+_ONE_CC_PYTHON([=2.7], [2_7])
 if test -f "$PYTHON" ; then found_one=$PYTHON ; PYTHONS="$PYTHON $PYTHONS" ; fi
 unset PYTHON
 _ONE_CC_PYTHON([=2.6], [2_6])
diff --git a/config/python.m4 b/config/python.m4
index c8c5e30..4d0366e 100644
--- a/config/python.m4
+++ b/config/python.m4
@@ -42,7 +42,7 @@ AC_DEFUN([AM_PATH_PYTHON],
   dnl $prefix/lib/site-python in 1.4 to $prefix/lib/python1.5/site-packages
   dnl in 1.5.
   m4_define_default([_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST],
-                      [python python2 python2.5 python2.6 python2.4 python2.3 python2.2 dnl
+                      [python python2 python2.7 python2.6 python2.4 python2.3 python2.2 dnl
 python2.1 python2.0 python1.6 python1.5])

   m4_if([$1],[],[
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I had tried a similar patch but messed up in a couple different aspects of it. You have saved the day

Comment: 7 years later, this is helping me port this same lib to Python 3!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install python2.6 from sources http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.9/

Or tryout pyenv https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Comment: Neither of these seem like terrible options to me. Trying pyenv right now, I'll let you know if it works out. However, do you know if there's a way to configure install for 2.7?